# Add text to Floating Button in Android

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have created a simple floating menu. The floating menu works fine.

But I want to add some text to left side of the menu as shown in the below image.

[image]

Can some one help me to add some text before the floating buttons like images I have shown.

**Floating menu xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_ticket_details" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_floating_forward" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_floating_note" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_floating_replay" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_floating_replay" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity class**

```
public class TicketDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView tv_ticket_id;
    ImageView back_arrow;
    TextView ticket_status;
    TextView ticket_overdue;
    TextView ticket_subject;

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public String BASEURL;
    public ApplicationEnvironmentURL applicationEnvironment;

    private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
    private FloatingActionButton fab,fab1,fab2,fab3;
    private Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_details);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_details_floating);

        applicationEnvironment = new ApplicationEnvironmentURL(this.context);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String ticket_id = intent.getStringExtra("ticket_id");


        back_arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV_td_leftarrow_bar);
        back_arrow.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        /*********************** Floating Icon *****************************************************/
        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab3 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab3);
        fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
        rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab3.setOnClickListener(this);
        /*******************************************************************************************/


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.fab:
                animateFAB();
                break;
            case R.id.fab1:
                break;
            case R.id.fab2:
                break;
            case R.id.fab3:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void animateFAB(){

        if(isFabOpen){
            fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
            fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab1.setClickable(false);
            fab2.setClickable(false);
            fab3.setClickable(false);
            isFabOpen = false;
            Log.d("ZF-Fab", "close");

        } else {

            fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
            fab1.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab1.setClickable(true);
            fab2.setClickable(true);
            fab3.setClickable(true);
            isFabOpen = true;
            Log.d("ZF-Fab","open");

        }
    }

..............more
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know FAB need a `drawable` to show on its view so to show text on it you need to create `drawble` with text on it so create it using below code.

```
 FloatingActionButton fab3 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab3);
 fab3.setDrawble or source there must a method

 TextDrawable trxtDrawable = new TextDrawable("AB");
 fab3.setImageDrawable(trxtDrawable);
```

**TextDrawable:**

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;

    public TextDrawable(String text) {

        this.text = text;

        this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(22f);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setShadowLayer(6f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hy tnx.  tried. but this one removes the icon and then inserts the text. i want to have both as shown in above image.

Comment: @SathyaBaman you can modify `TextDrawable`  add an `ImageView` in it and also pass `R.id.xyz` in it as a param. then use this id as ImageView resources to `imageview.`

Comment: @SathyaBaman if my post helps you little please vote up and tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using based off of the code started out by @Sohail Zahid above but I couldn't follow his comment/get it to work about how to add the image using an ImageView so I ended up using a Bitmap instead.

Also I couldn't get several of the methods to work so I passed the activity that calls it in the constructor.

I'm super new to this so my apologies if I didn't follow any best practices, I'd be happy to modify the code further if there are betters ways of doing it.

When creating the class, do so by right clicking on your java>com.example.appname and selecting New>Java Class>Class (Name: TextDrawable)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;

public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final Bitmap icon;
    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;

    public TextDrawable(Activity activity, String text) {

        this.text = text;

        // load image to show alongside the text
        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart);

        this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(42f); // make much bigger -- I'm just using a number for my text
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setShadowLayer(6f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, -15, 0, paint); // icon offset slightly to the left
        canvas.drawText(text, 35, 40, paint); // offset to have number to the right of the icon
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

The result I have looks like this:
[image]